# Can Android push notification be processed without User clicking on it?

Tags: android, push-notification

I just want to send a push notification and process it without even letting the user know about it.

So is it possible in Android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.
You can implement it anyway you want to in the intent receiver's `onMessage` method.